# При изменение массива используя async/await возвращает Promise pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Пытаюсь получить из базы сообщения чатов, но до отправке на клиент хочу добавить в массив чатов ещё имя кто написал сообщения, и тут у меня возникает 2 проблемы. 1 - при добавлении item.name = user.username; в item нет свойства name. 2 - то что результат нового массива [ Promise {  } ]. Как можно решить эти проблемы?

```
exports.chatmsg = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const chat = await Chat.find();
        if (chat.length) {
            const addUserNameToChat = chat.map(async item => {
                try {
                    let user = await User.findById(item.sender);
                    if (user) {
                        item.name = user.username;
                        console.log(item);
                        return item;
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });

            console.log(addUserNameToChat);

            res.status(200).send(addUserNameToChat);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ error: error, message: 'Could not retrieve users' });
    }
};
```

Comment: нельзя использовать `async/await` в `map`. нужно использовать `Promise.all` или `forof`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> const addUserNameToChat = chat.map(async item => {});

Асинхронная функция в `map`  (на его месте может быть `forEach`, `filter`, etc.) возвращает объект `Promise`.

Чтобы код сработал так, как вы ожидаете нужно или немного реорганизовать код, или дождаться выполнения промисов.

Для этого вы можете использовать конструкции внутри которых поддерживаются асинхронные вызовы:

```
const chat = await Chat.find();
for (const item of chat) {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(item.sender);
        if (user) {
            item.name = user.username;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

res.status(200).send(chat);
```

Или использовать `Promise.all` для того чтобы синхронно запустить эти задачи:

```
const chat = await Chat.find();

const addUserNameToChat = await Promise.all(
    chat.map(async (item) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findById(item.sender);
            if (user) {
                item.name = user.username;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        return item;
    })
);

res.status(200).send(addUserNameToChat);
```

Но в вашем случае я бы лучше подумал о том как приджоинить `sender`-а ещё при первом запросе данных `const chat = await Chat.find();`

Comment: я попробывал ваш код 1я проблема осталась, то что не добавляеться в обьект item.name = user.username;

Comment: вы попробовали 1вый или 2рой предложенный код? распечатали в консоль item? заполнен ли sender? есть ли в коллекции пользователей запись с таким идентификатором? распечатали в консоль user?

Comment: да, попробовал 2 варианта и в каждом не добавляеться name. [ Promise { } ] - эта проблема решилась

Comment: распечатали в консоль item? заполнен ли sender? есть ли в коллекции user запись с таким идентификатором? распечатали в консоль user?

Comment: const user = await User.findById(item.sender); console.log(user.username)  да User находиться, такой есть по id. но перед отправкой res.status(200).send(chat); если сделать console.log(chat) то там нет свойства name у элементов

Comment: ну, это уже другой вопрос. разбирайтесь с тем объект какого класса в item, что позволяет orm, как она относится к кастомным атрибутам и т.д.